# Can one define NSFound macro?

Tags: ios, objective-c

This may sound like a silly question but Apple provides us with NSNotFound but why didn't they provide one called NSFound? Is there a way one can define a NSFound macro on their own?

The reason I am asking all this is that in order for me to check if a string "contains" a certain character I have to do double negative i.e.

```
if ([XML rangeOfString:@"error" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
{
     //server is down
}
else
{
     //server is up
}
```

At least for me this would have been so much easier to read if I could simply do this instead

```
if ([XML rangeOfString:@"error" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location == NSFound)
{
 //server is down
}
else
{
 //server is up
}
```

If I want to define NSFound or SAMFound, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Because rangeOfString returns the location of the string.  What good would an NSFound constant be if you didn't actually get the location where the string was found?

Comment: @JAL that didn't make sense. If rangeOfString returns the location of string then that's good and that's what I want. If its not found do something else. It would go in the else block

Comment: If you were to define a macro for this, given the multitude of possible "found" cases you'd really need to just do something like `#define NSFound(X) (X) != NSNotFound` which means you'd have to use it like `NSFound([XML rangeOfString:@"error" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location)` and personally, that's less readable and non-standard too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is really with the design pattern methods like `rangeOfString` follow - using a single return value for both valid results, of which there are many, and failure indications, of which there is one. You can test for a single failure value with a comparison to a constant, `NSNotFound` in this case, but you cannot likewise test for many possible values with a simple comparison - instead you use the "double negative" you don't like.

If you find it too ugly change it... Maybe:

```
@interface NSString (SamExtras)

- (BOOL) SAMcontainsString:(NSString *)string options:(NSStringCompareOptions)options;

@end

@implementation NSString (SamExtras)

- (BOOL) SAMcontainsString:(NSString *)string options:(NSStringCompareOptions)options
{
   return [self rangeOfString:string options:options].location != NSNotFound;
}

@end
```

Which would allow you to use:

```
if ([XML SAMcontainsString:@"error" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch])
{
   //server is down
}
else
{
   //server is up
}
```

with no double negative. You can write the category once and use it in all your projects.

HTH

Comment: perfect. That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

*Double Negative* doesn't have the consequences in code as it does in grammar.

The reason they provide a *not* found, as opposed to a found version, is simply the *not* found value is a single (supposedly invalid) value and everything else is valid.  It's therefore simpler to define this single, invalid value.

Also it makes more sense (more efficient, avoiding a double-search and less code) to store the `NSRange` in a local variable in order to firstly test for validity and then to use the value:

```
NSRange range = [XML rangeOfString:@"error" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    // Do thing with range
} else {
    // Complain
}
```

Comment: I suppose you're assuming that he cares to use the range for anything other than test, but good to point out I guess.

Comment: @BrandonBuck Yes I am making that assumption.

Comment: All I am trying to do is get away from this double negative != NSNotFound ... this just rewrites what I already know

Comment: @SamB You asked why they didn't provide an `NSFound`, so I explained why.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing whatever wrong with your original test:

```
if ([XML rangeOfString:@"error" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) {
```

If all you need to know is whether `XML` contains the string `@"error"`, that test answers the question and is a perfectly legitimate and idiomatic way to ask it. Observe that even the documentation tells you that `containsString:` is nothing but a front for calling `rangeOfString:options:`!

If you really want to know what the positive version would be, it would be to test the `length` of the returned range and see if it is the same as the `length` of `@"error"`. The `length` of a not-found range is `0`.